# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added even after .isAdded()

Tags: android, android-fragments

Everytime I run my code this error comes up

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: MyFragment{19704129 #4 id=0x7f0e0077}

Here is the code

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
if (!myFragment.isAdded())
    transaction.add(R.id.container, myFragment, myFragment.getTag());
transaction.commit();
```

What? Why? How?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a lot of people run into this.  The same problem keeps coming up and only one person found a reasonable answer.

The commit call does not actually add your fragment to the activity.  It queues a request to be processed later.  If a second request for the new fragment is queued ahead of the commit request, isAdded() will return false, and a second request to add the fragment will be queued, and that duplicate fragment exception will be thrown.

The clean solution is to call FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions() before check to see if you fragment has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments can be added to the Activity and not be visible. By default, a `Fragment` is visible.

Whether a fragment is added or detached from an Activity is unrelated to the visibility. You can only add a Fragment once.

If you are attempting to control the visibility of a particular fragment there are other methods that allow you to do this. If this is for toggling between different fragments, I would recommend having a look at the hidden state.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isHidden()

Comment: But is `isAdded()` always true? I'm using `Fragment.hide()` and `Fragment.show()`.

Comment: If you haven't added the fragment to the fragment manager `isAdded()` should not return true.

Comment: But it does. And it cannot be added because it's already added. This is so strange.